# Open a url in c# get content close the page directly afther

Tags: c#, browser, openurl

At the moment im working on a system for a friend. My friend has a website where you can login to and it will keep some things as a session stored like an ID.

Now im making a program that will go to an URL that will display your session ID if your logged in otherwise it will show U instead of an ID.

Now i have created a simple thing for it:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create((url + page));
            request.UserAgent = "GameLoadingService";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

But when this executes you will get the U even though you are logged in in your browser.
Sooo this means that it doesnt open it like your browser and i need it to because then it will give me the ID.

So my question is if there is in any way possible to open a url and get the page content from that url, but this url needs to be opend as if its in your active browser. Because you will need to have your browser open and logged in to run this program.

Comment: You might want to look into the [Selenium C# driver](https://www.google.com/search?q=Selenium+C%23+driver&oq=Selenium+C%23+driver&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1063j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or use `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`

Comment: I run into this a lot with WebForms and other web frameworks.  Most of the time you can work with this by requesting the login page, storing all the cookies and form variables like "__ASPX_VIEWSTATE", and then posting it all back to the Login url with the correct username/password.  Now request any other page, but be sure to pass in any cookies and page state form variables as well.